# Separate parts of an svg file

Tags: css, svg

Does anyone know if I can separate each of the objects that the image has from an SVG file? Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SVG is embed directly you can select each element/path object for styling/changes. If the SVG is added via img element you would need to save the SVG and embed it directly.

If using Adobe Illustrator it's easy to put each element on a separate layer with individual naming conventions to allow easy selection via ID tags.

Answer (score 1):

Different paths in the SVG file should represent every individual image, hence you can extract the paths into separate SVG files.